# Adding Multiple Records To Database Using ASP.Net MVC Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, insert

I have a table which holds records that I would like to add to a database table.

I have a CRUD functionality in my website, but that is for the user to interact with and add on item at a time using HTML forms. I want to be able to loop through each item in my table and add it to the database. Here is an example of my model:

```
public class Photo
{
    public int PhotoId { get; set; }
    public int ListingId { get; set; }
    public string LocationAndName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUploaded { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have an array that contain the following values:
ListingId
LocationName
DateUploaded
Description
How can I populate all these in my database with a loop?

Answer (score 0):

From a performance standpoint I would recommend doing a bulk insert instead of adding each row at a time in the database.

With EF the code should look something like this:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (var context = new DataContext())
    {
        foreach(var photo in photos)
        {
            context.Photo.Add(photo);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    scope.Complete();   
}
```

If atomicity is not important for your scenario then you can leave out the transactional part.

Comment: That sounds very good. I just wanted to ask one more question regarding this. If I have a Table called Photos and I am looping for each photo in photos. How is the context.Photo.Add(photo) going to bind the properties? I am assuming that I will have to have named properties in my array?

Comment: It is sufficient to have objects of type Photo in the photos array.

Comment: So something like this would work right?                                  List<Photo> items = new List<Photo>();                       And then I could do for each item in items?

Comment: Thanks, you are a star. I will try this today.